# Is there any way to use comments for taxonomy pages?

Tags: 7, entities, taxonomy-terms, comments

I want to add a block like message board/chatbox in my taxonomy pages.

Best and simple way to do it is comments.

Is there any way to use comments for taxonomy pages?